# Write and read specific variables from external file in Python

Tags: python, pickle

I'm writing a program where I would like to both read and write specific variables with different data types from/to an external file.
The closest I've gotten after trying a few different modules, is by using pickle.
Pickle seems great as it understands the different data types, but it falls short as I understand it reads line from line from the top instead of being able to call specific variables by name as you can from an external .py file.

This module, and other modules, also seem to overwrite the whole file if you write new or change existing variables, so you would have to rewrite all the data if you'd actually only like to change one of them.

See code example down below. Sorry for the long code, I just wanted to be thorough in my explanation.

In this particular program it doesn't matter if the file is humanly readable or not.
Could anyone point me in the direction of a module that can handle this, or tell me what I might be doing wrong?

```
import pickle

variable1 = "variable1"
variable2 = "variable2"

pickle_out = open("db.pkl","wb")
pickle.dump(variable1, pickle_out)
pickle.dump(variable2, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()

#So I'll load the variables in again

pickle_in = open("db.pkl", "rb")
variable1 = pickle.load(pickle_in)
variable2 = pickle.load(pickle_in)
print(variable2)
variable2

#Everything good so far.
#But let's say I only want to load variable2 because I can't remember which 
#line it was written on.

pickle_in = open("db.pkl", "rb")
variable2 = pickle.load(pickle_in)
print(variable2)
variable1

#Also, if I'd like to update the value of variable1, but leave the other 
#variables untouched, it wouldn't work as it would just overwrite the whole 
#file.

#Let's say I've loaded in the variables like at the line 17 print statement.

variable1 = "variable1_new"
pickle_out = open("db.pkl","wb")
pickle.dump(variable1, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()
pickle_in = open("db.pkl", "rb")
variable1 = pickle.load(pickle_in)
variable2 = pickle.load(pickle_in)
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
EOFError: Ran out of input

print (variable1)
variable1_new

#So the value of variable1 is correct, but variable2 is no longer in the 
#pickle-file as the whole file was overwritten.
```

Comment: You are looking for the `shelve` module - it's basically a database of individually-pickled objects.

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. Maybe you can use a lightweight database like sqlite3?

Comment: Are you using/ intending to use complex data types ? If not you may want to use `json` and work with a dictionary instead, it can hold fairly complex data, but no classes or function or the like (referring to the json not the dictionary). Without knowing the "worst" case you want to store hard to tell if `pickle` is the right module for you. I have worked through tutorials a long time ago, but I never came across a use-case where pickle was the best/easiest choice.

Comment: @jasonharper Thanks, I’ll look into that! It definitely sounds right :-)

Comment: @roganjosh Thanks for the tip! I’ll have to look into that as well :-)

Comment: I might defer on this one and say that `shelve` is better for your problem because I'm not familiar with it but it seems like it does what you want. Research that first. Happy coding :)

Comment: @dparolin Sorry for not being clear as to what kind of information I would like to store. It’s basically just lists and str/int variables. Perhaps I need to take a second look at json! :-)

Answer (score -1):

Based on your comment that the data stored is relatively simple, a JSON file may be easier to work with.

Consider the following file **config.json**:

```
{
    "str_var": "Somevalue1",
    "list_var": ["value2", "value3"],
    "int_var": 1,
    "nested_var": {
        "int_var": 5
    }
}
```

Now you can read and use the values as follows

```
import json

# With statement will close the file for us immediately after line 6
with open("config.json", "r") as config_file:
    # Load the data from JSON as a Python dictionary
    config = json.load(config_file)

# See all top level values
for key, value in config.items():
    print(key, ":", value, "Type", type(value))

# Use individual values
print(config["str_var"])
print(config["list_var"][0])
print(config["nested_var"]["int_var"])

# Do something constructive here
...

# Update some values (e.g. settings or so)
config["str_var"] = "Somevalue2"
config["int_var"] = 5
config["list_var"].append("value4")

# Write the file
json.dump(config, open("config.json", "w"), indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

Resulting in the following JSON file:

```
{
    "int_var": 5,
    "list_var": [
        "value2",
        "value3",
        "value4"
    ],
    "nested_var": {
        "int_var": 5
    },
    "str_var": "Somevalue2"
}
```

This allows you to e.g. load such a config file, and you are free to use any value in it specifically, no need to know the index.
Hope this gives you an idea how to handle your data using JSON.

Comment: json is not aplicable to some python variables types

Comment: @VasinYuriy You are correct, thus my initial question if the data is expected to be complex, in which other options are preferable, but if it is as simple as the OP posted JSON will work just fine.